# Magento 2.3.3: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPayment() on null

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

In one of my templates I was using this code in Magento 2.2.3:

```
$order = $this->getData('order'); // This returns NULL in Magento 2.3.3
$paymentTitle = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(); // This throws the error
```

After an update to 2.3.3 I am now getting the error mentioned in the header. Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: What is `$this` a reference to?  Is it a Magento object?

Comment: In which template you get order data? Please add more info in question.

Answer (score 1):

**You have something wrong with this line if it's returning null,**

```
$this->getData('order');
```

> Try to `var_dump` this code `$this->getData();` to see if you're
>   actually getting the 'order' in `$this->getData();`
>
> If not, then you need to check your `$this` object. If you're using
>   the template file, then you need to check which block you're calling
>   for this template file and check if you're getting the `order` object.

**You can try below code,**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository

    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getPaymentData()
    {
        $orderId = 1;
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $payment = $order->getPayment();
        $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
        echo $method->getTitle(); 
        echo $method->getCode(); 
    }

}
```

**Hope it helps.**